# AngularJS + jQuery Flot + Loading data with http.get from controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I've set up a directive to handle loading a jQuery Flot chart with AngularJS:

```
var Dashboard = angular.module('StatsDashboard', []);

Dashboard.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var chart = null;
            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
            var options = {}

            $.plot(elem, data, options);
            elem.show();
            }
        };
});
```

The directive loads from a controller:

```
function ChartCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('controllers/weekly_overview_charts.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.reg_vs_act = data;
        });
}
```

I'm getting a **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at parseData".**

Positive this is due to the async nature of the http function.

My question is, how can I make sure the data is returned before the directive attempts loading the flot chart?

Thanks!

Comment: There are actually a lot of examples of directives for flot.. I based my stuff off this one: https://gist.github.com/jrmoran/3966529   You'll need to setup a watch on the data, and make sure it's valid before you draw the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer to my own question:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(v){
    if(v)
    {
        chart = $.plot(elem, v, options);
        elem.show();
    }
});
```

This was tripping scope.$watch up:

```
var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
```

In this case should be simply attrs.ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Erik's answer answers the problem, just wanted to add that the error displayed is probably that `$scope.reg_vs_act` is undefined. So - to resolve the error and support initing the chart before data is available you could probably use:

```
function ChartCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.reg_vs_act = []; //Init to array with length 0
    $http.get('controllers/weekly_overview_charts.php').success(function(data) {
        angular.copy(data, $scope.reg_vs_act); //Assignment would also work with a watch, but you would loose the reference to the original array
    });
}
```